# SmtpClient.SendMail works in PowerShell, not in C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, smtp, system.net.mail

I have some strange troubles sending a simple mail via C#.

When i try this in Powershell - IT WORKS:

```
$EmailTo = "recipient@provider.com"
$EmailFrom = "sender@provider.com"
$Subject = "Test" 
$Body = "Test Body" 
$SMTPServer = "smtp.provider.com" 

$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $false 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

When i do "the same" in C#, i get a SmtpException "Error sending mail" with InnerException "Could connect to Remote Server":

```
string host = "smtp.provider.com";
int port = 25;
string user = "username";
string pwd = "password";
string from = "sender@provider.com";
string to = "recipient@provider.com";
string sub = "Test";
string body = "Test Body";

Email.SendSmtpMail(host, port, user, pwd, from, to, sub, body, null, false);
```

where `SendSmtpMail`looks like this:

```
public static void SendSmtpMail(string host, int port, string user, string password, string from, string to, string subject, string body, string[] attachments = null, bool enableSSL = false)
{
    using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(host, port))
    {
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);

        if (attachments != null)
        {
            foreach (string a in attachments)
                msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(a));
        }

        smtpClient.Send(msg);
    }
}
```

Any ideas why C# Code fails while PS version is working smooth?

Comment: just to be complete: If i replace the host name with it's IP there is no difference, enableSSL has to be false in my case and there was no typo in credentials, etc... feeling helpless atm :/

Comment: Are you using a proxy server anywhere?

Comment: @DavidG No i don't.  
I run these two blocks of code from the same machine, with Powershell ISE and Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 2 respectively

Comment: So you're not on a corporate network of some sort?

Comment: gmail uses port 587

Comment: @CeOnSql can you remove references to gmail from your code since you are not using that as your SMTP? It is confusing otherwise.

Comment: @user1666620 good point, changed to `provider.com`

Comment: @DavidG: no i am testing with a standard standalone win7 machine, the provider is outside in www. Something like gmail, hotmail, etc...

Comment: How about a local firewall? Do you have anti-virus installed? That will likely block port 25 outgoing connections

Comment: @CeOnSql there doesn't seem to be anything obvious wrong with your code. So either there is something being left out, or there is a problem with your configuration settings, or something is preventing you from connecting to the SMTP. Check your firewall to make sure the port you are using is open and try testing again with antivirus disabled.

Comment: If it were firewall one would think the power shell script would fail as well particularly if port 25 was being blocked.  Have you tried setting your host and port values explicitly vs through the constructor and place a break point to verify properties are getting passed to the method correctly.

Comment: @Bearcat9425: Yes that's what's confusing me the most. Why should firewall or antivir block visual studio and powershell works fine? Is this possible?
I tried setting port, host, credentials explicitly in every combination. Stil the error occurs at `smtpClient.Send(msg);`

Comment: could one be running as administrator and the other not?

Comment: both a running under administrator privileges, but it doesn't matter - same situation if i run both without admin privileges

Comment: Sorry to bump this up but have you found a solution to this one? I'm in a similar situation and have been lost for a long time. Mine was a bit different because the code is working on my local and other servers but on one specific server, it's not working. In that server, I tried sending via PowerShell and it worked which added to my confusion.